How does $3^{-\ln(n)}$ become $\frac{1}{n^{\ln(3)}}$?
$3^{-\ln(n)} =\frac{1}{n^{\ln(3)}}$.
I can't figure out how to get from the left side of the equation to the right. Any tips?

$x=e^{\log x}$ if $x>0$

Does this answer your question? How do we prove that $a^{\log{b}} = b^{\log{a}}$ for $a > 1$ and $b > 1$?

$a^b:=e^{b\ln a}$. Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

For any $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}_+^*$,
$$a^{\ln(b)}=e^{\ln(b)\ln(a)}=e^{\ln(a)\ln(b)}=b^{\ln(a)}$$
Apply this with $a=3$ and $b=n$.

Note that
$$
\dfrac{1}{3^{\ln\left(n\right)}}=\dfrac{1}{n^{\ln\left(3\right)}}
$$
which means $n^{\ln\left(3\right)}=3^{\ln\left(n\right)}$, then take $\ln$ to both sides and you get
$\ln\left(3\right)\,\ln\left(n\right)=\ln\left(3\right)\,\ln\left(n\right)$.
NB: $n\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Here is one way to show this.
Start by rewriting the expression
$$3^{-\ln(n)}=\frac{1}{3^{\ln(n)}}$$
Now, we can rewrite the denominator as such
$$3^{\ln(n)}=e^{\ln(3^{\ln(n)})}$$
Also, using the properties of logarithms, we can say
$$e^{\ln\left(3^{\ln(n)}\right)}=e^{\ln(n)\cdot\ln(3)}=\left(e^{\ln(n)}\right)^{\ln (3)}=n^{\ln(3)}$$
If we substitute this back into the original expression, we get
$$3^{-\ln(n)}=\frac{1}{3^{^{\ln(n)}}}=\frac{1}{n^{\ln(3)}}$$
Hope this helps! :)
